# How can we get a model instance not by model pk in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to get a model instance from my record in `django-rest-framework (DRF)` api.

On default we can get an instance of model by a particular `pk`

```
/api/animal/1/
```

But how can we get an instance with another model property supposed the `animal` model may have a `herd_id` property?

I am using this viewset to handle the crud.

```
class AnimalViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    `update` and `destroy` actions.
    """
    queryset = Animal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnimalSerializer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `lookup_field` attribute on the class.

```
class AnimalViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    lookup_field = 'herd_id'
```

See [the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#attributes).